# Animated header using scroll event and adding class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to animate the header to change height and font size when a user scrolls. I am using a function to add a class to the header when scroll is > a certain number but when tested the header remains the same. I will include my html, css and JS below.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">

<head>
    <title>Alison Hurman</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- ENTER KEYWORDS <meta name="keywords" content=""> -->
    <!-- ENTER DESCRIPTION <meta name="description" content=""> -->
    <!-- ENTER FINAL URL <meta name="canonical" content="http://www." property="canonical"> -->

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Oswald:300,400|Sansita|Noto+Sans|Kalam' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> <!--Google fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"> <!-- Link to main style sheet -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- JQuery CDN -->
    <script src="javascript/animated-header.js"></script> <!-- JS for animated Header -->

</head>

<body id="pptpp">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
            <li class="leftnav"><a href="#AboutMe">ABOUT ME</a></li>
            <li class="leftnav"><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></li>
            <li class="leftnav"><a href="Attend.html">ATTEND</a></li>
            <li class="rightnav"><a href="Blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
            <li class="rightnav"><a href="Freebies.html">FREEBIES</a></li>
            <li class="rightnav"><a href="Social.html">SOCIAL MEDIA</a></li>    
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="Page">

        <div id="OptInContent">
            <div id="OptInPlaceholder">
                <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center;">OPT IN PLACEHOLDER</p>
            </div>   
        </div>

        <div id="MainContent">
            <div id="AboutMe">
            <a id="AboutMe"><h2>ABOUT ME</h2></a>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare sem eget fringilla scelerisque. Nullam commodo, risus nec interdum tempus, velit ipsum rhoncus mi, id finibus turpis turpis quis neque. Phasellus nec sem nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Integer massa mi, posuere a justo ac, lobortis mollis neque. Sed vitae pharetra enim. Duis faucibus pretium augue quis tempor. Vestibulum quis mi ultrices, maximus orci sed, dignissim augue. Integer a turpis sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In molestie ac purus eu porttitor. Morbi cursus imperdiet urna, a semper turpis viverra scelerisque. Mauris vel urna sit amet nunc vestibulum sagittis. Curabitur quam nisi, imperdiet et venenatis non, aliquet a urna. Sed pretium dolor diam, ac condimentum elit aliquet quis. Praesent arcu urna, rhoncus ac enim quis, tristique gravida diam. </p>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare sem eget fringilla scelerisque. Nullam commodo, risus nec interdum tempus, velit ipsum rhoncus mi, id finibus turpis turpis quis neque. Phasellus nec sem nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Integer massa mi, posuere a justo ac, lobortis mollis neque. Sed vitae pharetra enim. Duis faucibus pretium augue quis tempor. Vestibulum quis mi ultrices, maximus orci sed, dignissim augue. Integer a turpis sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In molestie ac purus eu porttitor. Morbi cursus imperdiet urna, a semper turpis viverra scelerisque. Mauris vel urna sit amet nunc vestibulum sagittis. Curabitur quam nisi, imperdiet et venenatis non, aliquet a urna. Sed pretium dolor diam, ac condimentum elit aliquet quis. Praesent arcu urna, rhoncus ac enim quis, tristique gravida diam. </p>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare sem eget fringilla scelerisque. Nullam commodo, risus nec interdum tempus, velit ipsum rhoncus mi, id finibus turpis turpis quis neque. Phasellus nec sem nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Integer massa mi, posuere a justo ac, lobortis mollis neque. Sed vitae pharetra enim. Duis faucibus pretium augue quis tempor. Vestibulum quis mi ultrices, maximus orci sed, dignissim augue. Integer a turpis sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In molestie ac purus eu porttitor. Morbi cursus imperdiet urna, a semper turpis viverra scelerisque. Mauris vel urna sit amet nunc vestibulum sagittis. Curabitur quam nisi, imperdiet et venenatis non, aliquet a urna. Sed pretium dolor diam, ac condimentum elit aliquet quis. Praesent arcu urna, rhoncus ac enim quis, tristique gravida diam. </p>
            </div>

            <div id="Help">
                <h2>HOW I CAN HELP</h2>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare sem eget fringilla scelerisque. Nullam commodo, risus nec interdum tempus, velit ipsum rhoncus mi, id finibus turpis turpis quis neque. Phasellus nec sem nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Integer massa mi, posuere a justo ac, lobortis mollis neque. Sed vitae pharetra enim. Duis faucibus pretium augue quis tempor. Vestibulum quis mi ultrices, maximus orci sed, dignissim augue. Integer a turpis sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In molestie ac purus eu porttitor. Morbi cursus imperdiet urna, a semper turpis viverra scelerisque. Mauris vel urna sit amet nunc vestibulum sagittis. Curabitur quam nisi, imperdiet et venenatis non, aliquet a urna. Sed pretium dolor diam, ac condimentum elit aliquet quis. Praesent arcu urna, rhoncus ac enim quis, tristique gravida diam. </p>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare sem eget fringilla scelerisque. Nullam commodo, risus nec interdum tempus, velit ipsum rhoncus mi, id finibus turpis turpis quis neque. Phasellus nec sem nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Integer massa mi, posuere a justo ac, lobortis mollis neque. Sed vitae pharetra enim. Duis faucibus pretium augue quis tempor. Vestibulum quis mi ultrices, maximus orci sed, dignissim augue. Integer a turpis sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In molestie ac purus eu porttitor. Morbi cursus imperdiet urna, a semper turpis viverra scelerisque. Mauris vel urna sit amet nunc vestibulum sagittis. Curabitur quam nisi, imperdiet et venenatis non, aliquet a urna. Sed pretium dolor diam, ac condimentum elit aliquet quis. Praesent arcu urna, rhoncus ac enim quis, tristique gravida diam. </p>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare sem eget fringilla scelerisque. Nullam commodo, risus nec interdum tempus, velit ipsum rhoncus mi, id finibus turpis turpis quis neque. Phasellus nec sem nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Integer massa mi, posuere a justo ac, lobortis mollis neque. Sed vitae pharetra enim. Duis faucibus pretium augue quis tempor. Vestibulum quis mi ultrices, maximus orci sed, dignissim augue. Integer a turpis sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In molestie ac purus eu porttitor. Morbi cursus imperdiet urna, a semper turpis viverra scelerisque. Mauris vel urna sit amet nunc vestibulum sagittis. Curabitur quam nisi, imperdiet et venenatis non, aliquet a urna. Sed pretium dolor diam, ac condimentum elit aliquet quis. Praesent arcu urna, rhoncus ac enim quis, tristique gravida diam. </p>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Main Content -->
    </div> <!-- Page -->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#Page {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

/*
.wrapper {
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
*/

header {
    background-color: #E9DCCD;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-size: 160%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #339933;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

/*
header h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

*/

.scroll {
    height: 50px; 
    font-size: 80%;
}

/*header.shrink h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
*/

#center-column {
    background-color: white;
    width: 1080px;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
}

nav li a {
    color: #339933;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: black;
}

nav li.leftnav {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

nav li.leftnav a {
    padding-right: 40px;
}

nav li.rightnav {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

#OptInContent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#OptInPlaceholder {
    width: 1080px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#MainContent {
    width: 100%;
}

#AboutMe {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: -20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#AboutMe h2 {
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    color: #339933;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    border-color: #339933;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 45%;
    margin-left: 45%;
}

#AboutMe p {
    padding-left: 30px;
}

#Help {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: -20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#Help h2 {
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    color: #339933;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    border-color: #339933;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 45%;
    margin-left: 45%;
}

#Help p {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

JS:

```
/*jslint browser: true*/ 
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {  
            $('#header').addClass("scroll");
        } else {
            $('#header').removeClass("scroll");
        }
    });
});
```

As of right now the header remains exactly the same once I scroll and no animation takes place. I'm unsure what's causing it not to trigger. Help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding class `.scroll` instead of `scroll` which means that the selector would then be `..scroll`.

Change `addClass(".scroll")` to `addClass("scroll")` and `removeClass(".scroll")` to `removeClass("scroll")` then it will work.

Try the snippet below.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
        $('header').addClass("scroll");
    }
    else {
        $('header').removeClass("scroll");
    }
});
```

```css
header {
    background-color: #E9DCCD;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-size: 160%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #339933;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.scroll {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
     <ul>
      <li class="leftnav"><a href="#AboutMe">ABOUT ME</a></li>
      <li class="leftnav"><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></li>
      <li class="leftnav"><a href="Attend.html">ATTEND</a></li>
      <li class="rightnav"><a href="Blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
      <li class="rightnav"><a href="Freebies.html">FREEBIES</a></li>
      <li class="rightnav"><a href="Social.html">SOCIAL MEDIA</a></li>    
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ac nisl sit amet libero gravida dictum vel id eros. Maecenas egestas nulla tincidunt, iaculis nisl vel, dignissim dolor. Phasellus pretium sed nisl at facilisis. Maecenas sed augue sem. Morbi facilisis, lacus eget efficitur tempus, est dolor lacinia urna, ultricies dignissim sem nisi quis eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce eros nisl, auctor sed tellus at, pulvinar pharetra nibh. Morbi maximus, lorem vitae malesuada semper, nulla velit volutpat orci, non accumsan eros libero id arcu.

  Fusce eleifend lobortis tortor, at cursus libero cursus sit amet. Curabitur luctus neque non leo commodo placerat. Donec at condimentum tellus. Nam id lectus at ex ornare bibendum eget eu sapien. In tincidunt vestibulum lacus eget mattis. Suspendisse massa neque, malesuada a cursus quis, semper luctus lectus. Etiam non aliquam dui, ac pharetra purus. Cras quis massa ac orci facilisis porta a ut dolor.

  Sed tristique lorem ultrices nulla congue lacinia. Proin sed arcu pretium, vestibulum ligula sed, venenatis diam. Aliquam suscipit vel enim id malesuada. Sed vel efficitur nibh, ut fermentum erat. Nunc commodo auctor sapien, et fringilla leo imperdiet sit amet. In vel lorem dui. Pellentesque congue erat ante, a venenatis dui tincidunt a. Pellentesque eget leo urna. Integer iaculis semper magna. Nam vitae condimentum nisi. Etiam libero elit, scelerisque nec interdum eget, varius eu lectus.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
      $('header').addClass('scroll');
   } else {
      $('header').removeClass('scroll');
   }
});
```

Comment: Tried that already but it didn't work, also tried changing header to.header etc

Comment: Try to use this code @EthanBristow 
`$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
      $('header').addClass('scroll');
   } else {
      $('header').removeClass('scroll');
   }
});
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
      $('header').addClass('scroll');
   } else {
      $('header').removeClass('scroll');
   }
}); 
});
```

Comment: @EthanBristow Are you using external js file or internal code?

Comment: Is this code working? If not try to use this jQuery file.
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I'm not sure what part of the whole thing is causing it not to work, i tried that link though but unfortunatley still no change

Comment: Try to move the jQuery code to the top of the js file

Comment: Have you tried referencing jquery library like this?
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>